# EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET, spurious wakups and MTU

Tags: c++, asynchronous

The writer program sends a few MBs (hardly no delays) using multiple writes with a fixed buffer. The handlers are registered with the `EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET` flags.

1. MTU=16KB, writer buffer = 4KB or more. A few ~3 EAGAIN returned from the `write(...)` call (writing is restarted in the next event) and ~30 spurious EPOLLOUT (after all writes completes and data is considered to be sent).
2. MTU=16KB, writer buffer = 2KB. A few ~5 EAGAIN and a few (2-5) spurious EPOLLOUT events - logs suggest that the writer and the reader go simultaneously in this case.
3. MTU=16KB, writer buffer < 1KB. A few ~5 EAGAIN and a no spurious EPOLLOUT events.
4. MTU=1-5KB, writer buffer = 4KB. A few ~5 EAGAIN and no spurious EPOLLOUT events.
5. MTU=50KB (on loopback) - 99% of events are spurious EPOLLOUT.

It does not seem that simple that
the EPOLLOUT is generated when buffer comes from full into the "some-space-available". The correlation with the MTU size is interesting.
Questions:

1) Having EPOLLOUT disabled unless the last write ended with the EAGAIN code - is the right pattern?

2) Bigger buffers or MTU suggest transmission of larger blocks of data
yielding in less TCP/IP buffer updates and less events. The practice shows opposite. Can any anyone can shed some light on this ?

Comment: why do you think EPOLLOUT is spurious?

Comment: Ok, 1) was just a clarification epoll interface I was learning· What about the 2) larger writes/packets should yield in less changes in the buffer, less EPOLLOUT events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPOLLOUT means that there is space in the buffer. It doesn't mean just a transition from no space to some space. You should only use it after you get EAGAIN from a send. Otherwise you just get a meaningless stream of EPOLLOUT events, because there almost always is space in the send buffer.

Re your (1), yes, that's the right way to use it. Just write until you get EAGAIN, then use EPOLLIUT to tell you when you can write again.

Comment: What about 2) ? It looks like larger writes/MTU caused some additional fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse two kinds of usages of `epoll`.  The key notions are "level-triggered (**LT**)" and "edge-triggered (**ET**)".

`man 7 epoll` states:

> > > An application that employs the EPOLLET flag should use nonblocking file descriptors to avoid having a blocking read or write starve a task that is handling multiple file descriptors.  The suggested way to use epoll as an edge-triggered (EPOLLET) interface is  as  follows:
> > >
> > > i   with nonblocking file descriptors; and
> > >       ii  by waiting for an event only after read(2) or write(2) return EAGAIN.
> > >
> > > By contrast, when used as a level-triggered interface (the default, when EPOLLET is not specified), epoll is simply a faster poll(2), and can be used wherever the latter is used since it shares the same semantics.

So my answers to your question are:

1. Yes, you are correct.
2. Now that you know what you observed were lots of **LT** `EPOLLOUT` though you had **ET** `EPOLLOUT` in mind, perhaps you need to change your conclusion.

Let me illustrate the difference between **ET** and **LT**.

```
Buf=Empty
 V ET
Buf=Avail LT
 V
Buf=Avail LT
 V
Buf=Avail LT
 V
Buf=Empty
 V ET
Buf=Avail LT
```